# How can I calculate whether one number is a power of another number?

Tags: python

I made `is_power_of` work by using the exact things they are telling you to do:

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
  # Base case: when number is smaller than base.
  if number < base:
    # If number is equal to 1, it's a power (base**0).
    return number==1

  # Recursive case: keep dividing number by base.
  return is_power_of(number/base, base)

print(is_power_of(8,2)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(64,4)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(70,10)) # Should be False
```

Comment: Maybe you should check if a log with the given base is an integer number?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
  # Base case: when number is smaller than base.
  if number < base:
    # If number is equal to 1, it's a power (base**0).
    return number == 1
  result = number//base
  # Recursive case: keep dividing number by base.
  return is_power_of(result, base)
```

Comment: This fails on `is_power_of(1,1)` or `is_power_of(2,1)`. And why `number//base` instead of `number/base` ?

Answer (score 3):

No recursion or brute force is required. Just logarithms.

When you have `number = base ** x`, you get `x = log(number) / log(base)`. Simply checking if x is an integer should give you the answer.

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
    return (math.log(number) / math.log(base)).is_integer()
```

If you want to handle negative numbers as well, you could just calculate x and then check that `base ** x` is equal to `number`

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
    x = math.log(abs(number)) / math.log(abs(base))
    return base ** x == number
```

Comment: fails on `is_power_of(2,1)` and similar.

Comment: @PatrickT good catch, because `log(1)` is zero. Could just `return False` if `base = 1 and number != 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
  # Base case: when number is smaller than base.
  if number < base:
    # If number is equal to 1, it's a power (base**0).
    if number == 1:
      return True

    else:
      return False
  # Recursive case: keep dividing number by base.
  return is_power_of(number/base , base)

print(is_power_of(8,2)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(64,4)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(70,10)) # Should be False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: fails on `is_power_of(2,1)` and similar.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is using recursion since it is asked in the chapter of this exercise.

So it will work like this

```
def is_power_of(number, base):
# Base case: when number is smaller than base.
number= number/base
 if number < base:
# If number is equal to 1, it's a power (base**0).
  return False
 else: 
  return True
return is_power_of(number, base)


print(is_power_of(8,2)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(64,4)) # Should be True
print(is_power_of(70,10)) # Should be False
```

Comment: `is_power_of(1,2)` returns `False`, but it should be `True`, as explicitly stated in the comment "If number is equal to 1, it's a power (base**0)." And `is_power_of(2,1)` returns `True`, but it should be `False`. Oh and your indentation is completely wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_power_of(number,base):
    if number == base:
        return True
    elif number < base:
        return False
    return is_power_of(number / base, base)
```

It is done by recursion

Comment: I am not a professional. And I am new here I tried to answer the above question my best even I tried to upload a picture with solutions and I can't upload it .Anyway this code  actually works . I don't know how to write correct form of code in here. I suffered a lot with this question ,till I can't find one.At last I figured it out.Any way thanks for you valuable comment.i will try to improve

Comment: @Sinan9605, please see [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for how to format your questions and answers.

Comment: Thanks dude .i'm catching up with it.Thanks for your help